Can integrating Google Maps in Flutter obtain mapsApiKey from the server and initialize it before using the map?
Can integrating Google Maps in Flutter not configure mapsApiKey in the project, but instead obtain mapsApiKey from the server and initialize it before using the map?
Flutter
Android
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_map_key"/>

iOS
// Add the following line, with your API key
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:mapsApiKey];
I want to get mapsApiKey from the server and initialize it before using the map.
